# A regex to match the smallest nested part first

Tags: java, python, regex

I am quite new to RegEx. I have not much experience. I already searched the internet and tried many things on regex101.com. Nothing seems to work.

This is the pattern:
`\\((.*?)\\)`

I use it in combination with **Java** 's *replaceAll* to add a `?:` to each `(...)` provided in a string (the user input).

**The user input is used as regular expression as well. But currently I am treating it as a normal String.**

Imagine this user input: `(Welcome, (StackOverflow|World)|Hello, Dad)`

What I want as the result is: `(?:Welcome, (?:StackOverflow|World)|Hello, Dad)`

But I only get the first `?:` : `(?:Welcome, (StackOverflow|World)|Hello, Dad)`

---

I think, I understand the problem. **I guess,** RegEx scans from right to left and is trying to get the smallest match (see `.*?` ). It searches for `(` till the next `)` . And this is `(Welcome, (StackOverflow|World)` .

---

What could I do to match these nested matches first? I **cannot** let the user modify their input. I have to find a better regex pattern to match from the smallest possible match to the greatest possible match, and not from the left to the right.

Comment: Just replace all `(` by `(?:`

Comment: @anubhava was about to say the same thing. Why complicate your life OP? Do you lack the excitement?

Comment: @anubhava: Hmmmm... Well... That's a really simple way. In many cases it may not work because the developer wants to only replace (...) and not for example `(-:` . But for me it should be a solution. Thank you for your help. However I am still searching a better solution. ;-)

Comment: Have in mind, that using user's input as regular expression might be painful. Imagine, that he puts `((a+)+)` and input `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!` and you have ReDoS.

Comment: Yeah. :) . Actually the most of regular expressions are denied in my program. However this one is needed.

Comment: I once had a problem and used regular expressions. Now I have two problems.

Comment: @xenteros Would that be refered to as a *regex-injection*?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes. This would be ReDoS due to regex-injection

Comment: If anyone tries to build the next computer virus infecting the whole world, regex would be a good choice. There will be no free decryption program since NO one will ever understand the regex code.  :)

Comment: You actually need to search for an unescaped `(` not followed with `?`.

Comment: Erm...could you explain that a bit? Why unescaped? Why without a `?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest searching for any unescaped `(` (so as not to add `?:` after literal `(`) that is not followed with `?` (to avoid matching lookarounds/non-capturing groups/etc,):

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)\((?!\?)
```

and replace with `$1(?:`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMKGAr/1).

Java declaration:

```
String pat = "(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\{2})*)\\((?!\\?)";
```

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\)` - no backslash immediately to the left of the current location
- `((?:\\{2})*)` - Group 1: zero or more even number of backslashes
- `\(`- a literal `(`...
- `(?!\?)` - that is not immediately followed with a literal `?`.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty good! Even if I don't really understand that magic spell, it works. In my case it's ok to ignore the closing `)` for insertion of the `?:` . Thank you very much.

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote, because it is very good and everything is explained.

Comment: And because the user can even escape its input from getting a `?:`